# What would bees be doing inside my furniture in the beginning of summer

Tags: entomology

I have an old chest of drawers in my garden shed. I've been noticing individual bees entering a closed drawer through the keyhole. Recently they've sealed that keyhole with a gray goo that's solidified and seems very hard to the touch at this point. I don't have anything terribly important in there but I'd have to break the goo if I wanted to pry the drawer open. What am I likely to find in there? If I don't disturb them should I be worried about a swarm of angry bees exiting at some point? It's currently the beginning of summer here in Europe.

EDIT:

I photographed 2 bee types that fly around in my garden (though another species might have been around a couple of months ago):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like they would be building a home or laying eggs. Are they still entering and leaving, or were those solitary bees?

Comment: Doesn't sound like honey bees (or other social bees). I'm guessing some sort of mason bee (Osmia) that has layed egg(s) and then covered the entry (that's the "masonry"). If it's not an emergency I'd say you should wait and let them grow up in there, they won't do any harm to you or your stuff.

Comment: I only saw solitary bees entering or leaving. It's not an emergency and I'm happy to leave them to grow up in there, the only thing I'd be worried about is if they are easily aggrevated when they mature since kids might disturb them by accident.

Comment: don't worry, they are absent parents. they leave food for the larvae and then leave. it's mostly social wasps that need to defend their colony that are aggressive.

Comment: As @picapica says, it could well be mason bees (*Osmia* spp.). Another possibility (but less likely) is carpenter bees, which will actually burrow into the wood. I'm reluctant to give a confident identification from your description without better ID of the actual species, though - if you can get a photo of a dead bee that would be better, or if you can simply describe them it would be a start.

Comment: I can't remember exactly what they look like because some time has passed between me noticing bees and then noticing the barricade they've built, but I remember them not seeming very different to the other bees (we have plenty of flowering plants in our garden so bees are very common) and the usual bee here looks like what a beekeeper might keep (I used to know a few).Sorry for the lack of detail but I'm a programmer, not a biologist.. There are also no dead or alive bees around the drawer right now, they are currently in total stealth mode.

Comment: @arboviral yes, my guess wasn't meant to be definitive. this question could possibly be considered answered (they are making nests for their young) but getting it down to species will be impossible without more information. keep an eye out for the new generation when they appear!

Comment: @picapica Oh yes, I understood. I would agree that mason bees are the most likely culprit, though!

Comment: @picapica will keep an eye out for them - I'll take a photo if possible, or of their nest if they escape before I can snap the photos. Any best guesses as to when I can expect them out?

Comment: I took photos of the 2 types of bees I can find in the garden now; one of them is very similar to bumblebees which is supposed to be typical of carpenter bees, but mine don't look like the carpenter bee pictures on Wikipedia (mine have hairier butts :P )

Comment: Since you have more than one species of bee this might help you.http://bugguide.net/node/view/475348 as should this site which has a dichotomous key for identification. http://www.discoverlife.org/ed/tg/How_to_use_the_discoverlife_guides.html

Comment: Thank you, that guide is explicitly made for North America though and I'm from Europe, would that information still apply to Europe in general?

Comment: you should add your location to the question. your pictures look like a honey bee and a bumble bee to me, but keep looking!